# XML Config file for SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: xml

Good Morning,
I need help with configuring an xml config file for Sharepoint Designer 2013. specifically, I'm looking for a way to disable the start options screen (regarding updates) so end users do not have to see it. This is an SCCM2012 install to a citrix environment. We've tried the following reg hacks, but it does not work for all users:

User Configuration – HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\FirstRun   Value Name: BootedRTM   Value Type: REG_DWORD   Value Data: 1
User Configuration – HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\General   Value Name: ShownFirstRunOptin   Value Type: REG_DWORD   Value Data: 1

I'm hoping to incorporate the above lines into my xml file (once we get them working) for my deployment. XML file below:

Comment: Somehow the file was never attached: <Configuration Product="SharePointDesigner">

 <Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />
</Configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:
We simply went through GPO instead of arguing with the XML file:
User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Office 2013 > Miscellaneous
Disable the Office Start Screen for all Office applications - Enable

User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Office 2013 > First Run
Disable First Run Movie - Enable
Disable Office First Run on application boot - Enable

User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Office 2013 > Privacy > Trust Center
Automatically receive small updates to improve reliability - Disable
Disable Opt-in Wizard on first run - Enable
Enable Customer Experience Improvement Program - Disable